# error: method parseUnknownField in class Builder

Tags: android, protocol-buffers

as a practicumer, i was tasked to work on MyTracks app. and I am currently working on the source code i found [here](http://github.com/jgillich/mytracks) .. when i imported the code to android studio, i got 3 errors on Sensor.java -- a class that has this statement

// Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
// source: proto/sensor.proto

and these are the ff errors:

1. error: method parseUnknownField in class Builder cannot be applied to given types;
   required: CodedInputStream,CodedOutputStream,ExtensionRegistryLite,int
   found: CodedInputStream,ExtensionRegistryLite,int
   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
   where MessageType,BuilderType are type-variables:
   MessageType extends GeneratedMessageLite declared in class Builder
   BuilderType extends Builder declared in class Builder
2. error: method parseUnknownField in class Builder cannot be applied to given types;
   required: CodedInputStream,CodedOutputStream,ExtensionRegistryLite,int
   found: CodedInputStream,ExtensionRegistryLite,int
   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
   where MessageType,BuilderType are type-variables:
   MessageType extends GeneratedMessageLite declared in class Builder
   BuilderType extends Builder declared in class Builder
3. Error:Execution failed for task ':myTracksLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

I hope you guys would help me out on this one because i badly need to  get this right. Thank you for any help you could offer.

Answer (score 4):

In all likelihood, the version of `protoc` (the protobuf code generator tool) which generated `Sensor.java` is different from the version of `libprotobuf.jar` that you're trying to compile against. These two things must be exactly the same version. You will either need to regenerate `Sensor.java` using a version of `protoc` matching your `libprotobuf.jar` or you will need to find a version of `libprotobuf.jar` matching the `protoc` which generated `Sensor.java`.

Answer (score 0):

just use this version it works for me :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.21.7</version>
    </dependency>
```